# How to show errors and warnings form an external validation tool in an Xtext editor?

Tags: xtext

I want to integrate an existing parser into my Xtext language that can produce errors and warnings with the exact position (line and column) in the source file.

Is it possible to add errors and warnings at specific locations in an Xtext language?

Context: there is an existing parser that can produce detailed problem reports. It would be fine to show the errors only if the user explicitly triggers a validation (because it might take a while to run).

Comment: you are referring to eclipse? how does that external validation tool work (what does it need as input)

Comment: yes I am referring to eclipse -- it takes the file as input and generates a list of problems that I would parse und add to the errors. The question is how would I add those errors. Obviously, I'd have to remove them when they are not applicable anymore...

Comment: Did you consider to call it in a check type normal validation rule on the model root

Comment: It's not part of the normal validation -- it is a kind of offline validation that is triggered manually and the customer wants to see the error messages inside the xtext file as if they would have been generated by the built in checks...

Similar to something like CheckStyle or http://www.ucdetector.org that have checks that you can run manually.

Comment: What about using an expensive check